# How can i add text in "$cordovaLocalNotification.schedule" for multiple ngCordova local notification dynamically?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Following is the way ngCordova docs shows how to add multiple local notifications

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule([{
    id: 1,
    text: "Multi Notification 1",
    sound: isAndroid ? 'file://sound.mp3' : 'file://beep.caf',
    at: dateObject,
    autoCancel: true
},{
    id: 2,
    title: "Local Notification Example",
    text: "Multi Notification 2",
    at: dateObject,
    autoCancel: true
}]);
```

I am iterating data coming from database so I have dynamic "id" and "date object". I ran it in a loop but only last notification gets scheduled even when ids are different so i found that i need to pass array of objects like shown above in "cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule" to get it done but i don't know how to do it dynamically.
Please help i need to submit my project and this is stuck.

## services.js

```
        for(var i in TestTimeTable)
        {
            var notificationDate = new Date(TestTimeTable[i].year, TestTimeTable[i].month, TestTimeTable[i].day, TestTimeTable[i].hour, TestTimeTable[i].minute, 0, 0);
            var notificationID = i + ref.getAuth().uid;


              $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
                id: notificationID,
                title: 'Feedback Reminder',
                text: 'Please Provide Lecture Feedback',
                at: notificationDate,
                autoCancel: true
              }).then(function (result) {
              });

        }

        cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", function (notification, state) {
            $state.go('courses');
        }, this)

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now, problem was that notification ID (var notificationID = i + ref.getAuth().uid;) was not numeric. Thanks

Comment: I could able to get only one notification only. I mean single notification is updating everytime. I want to display multiple notifications.